# Перемещение формы Windows Forms, С++Builder

Tags: c++

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как реализовать автоматическое перемещение формы по экрану.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Меняйте координаты формы:

```
Form->left = 100;
Form->top = 200;
```